# Efficient way of creating large table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database of 3 continents (Africa, Asia and Europe), different number of countries from each and different number of languages spoken in each country. For example,

```
Continent-Country-Language
Africa - Egypt - Arabic
Africa - Egypt - English
Africa - Somalia - English
Asia - China - English
Asia - China - Mandarin
Asia - China - Cantonese
Asia - Japan - japanese
Asia - Iraq - Arabic
Europe - Germany - German
Europe - Belgium - Dutch
Europe - Belgium - French
```

The table above becomes incredibly huge if 5 continents, 150 countries and 2000 languages are used! In addition if each variable is linked to a single external link, the total work becomes so painful.

My question is how can I create such large table in a more efficient way?

TIA!

Comment: create small tables and use foreign keys in the main table. i.e. create one table for countries, languages, etc.

Comment: 2000 records is nothing for mysql :)

Comment: MySQL can handle ___billions___ of rows mate! A couple of thousand rows will not give you scalability issues, trust me.  Google, Yahoo, LiveJournal,Technocarati all have MySQL installations with many billions of rows that delivers great performance.

Comment: @stefgosselin: He still needs normalization, even for 2000 records.

Comment: @stefgosselin, but I am actually looking for an efficient way rather than creating a huge table :(

Comment: @SM: Just note that these people are telling you that 2000 is not huge. It's tiny.

Comment: @ypercube Sure. Everybody want to normalize. Even though for read access [denormalized data is more efficient and easier to scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).  To be fair, it is easier to normalise first before denormalising.

Comment: I seriously doubt the claim that `denormalized data is more efficient and easier to scale`. Despite what Wikipedia, I'm sure there are exactly opposite views `normalized data are more efficient and easier to scale`.

Comment: @ypercube I think it is because denormalized data is more easily sharded, and can require less joins to get usable data from

Comment: Within the TYPO3 project there is an extension static_info_tables which provides all the information you need (in a different structure though). It also provides capital, address format etc.. Take a look at the SQL import file at http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/static_info_tables/current/info/ext_tables_static%252Badt.sql/

Comment: @Gaurav, how did you edit that mate?

Comment: @SM : select the content and click on {}

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

Create five tables - one for continents, one for countries, one to link languages and countries, and finally one for languages.

```
Continent       ContinentCountry    Country       CountryLanguage    Language
------------    ----------------    ----------    ---------------    -----------
continent_id <- continent_id        name          language_id     -> language_id
name            country_id       -> country_id <- country_id         name
```

This is called *Database Normalization*.

> The goal of database normalization is to decompose relations with anomalies in order to produce smaller, well-structured relations.

From Wikipedia's article on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Since the relation between `Country` and `Language` is probably many-to-many, a 4th table `CountryLanguage` would be suitable.

Comment: @Michael, @Ibu: If a country can appear in more than one continents in your data, then a `ContinentCountry` intermediate table would be suitable too.

Comment: how to make that table thing here as Michael did?

Comment: Continent   ContinentCountry    Country     CountryLanguage    Language
---------   ----------------    ----------  ---------------    --------
1 Africa 1   7         1 Belgium 1 9  1 Arabic
2 Asia  2   3  2 Egypt  1 1  2 cantonese
3 Europe 2   5  3 China  2 1  3 Dutch
  2   6  4 Germany 3 2  4 English
  3   1  5 Iraq  3 7  5 French
  3   4  6 Japan  3 9  6 German
  1   2    7 Somalia 4 5  7 Mandarin
      4 6  8 Spanish
      5 1  9 Dialect
      6 10  10 Japanese
      7 1    
      7 9    
      2 9

Comment: @SM you need to make each of these tables, probably in phpMyAdmin, then modify your create/update/delete logic to be compatible with your new database structure

Comment: @Michael, what did you mean by <- or -> symbol? Is it one separate table containing two columns with relational id numbers? TYSM!

Comment: @SM: `(b)a_id -> (a)id` means that table `b` has a column `a_id` that references a row of table `a` - basically meaning that this `b` row relates to the `a` row identified by the `b` row's `a_id` value.

Comment: @Michael, if all three tables have ids of 1, 2, 3...how would anyone or SQL would understand which id belongs to which table?

Comment: @SM: table `id` columns must be unique - make them `primary keys`

Comment: @Michael, I started that way. I have three tables and now confused how to "relationalize" them. For example, each table has the id = 10. Now how the relational table row {10 | 10} would assign the id 10? (Sorry if my problem is still vague and I think it is!)

Comment: @SM: Sorry, I'm having a little trouble finding the best way to answer this problem, would you consider opening a new question, so your problem can be addressed more verbosely?

Comment: Alright Michael! I will do it soon. Thanks for your kind cooperation.